# 70-80s gothic/horror romance novel with a cowboy and an alien

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror, western

It was set in the (US) wild west, but had a foreboding house.  There was a cowboy and I'm pretty sure there was an alien.  I don't remember why I keep thinking it was written like a gothic romance novel.

I'd like to read it again, simply because it was so 'odd'.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question). I'm certain you can remember more than you've told us,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It might be *The Hawkline Monster:  A Gothic Western* (1974) by Richard Brautigan.  That is a critically acclaimed science fiction, western, gothic, romance novel that was published in the mid-seventies.  The story takes place around 1900.  Two gunmen are hired to do a job at a creepy, isolated house on the western plains.  My paperback has a great painting of the house on the cover.  The gunmen were hired by twin sisters to kill a monster that lives in the ice caves beneath their house.  Their father, a scientist who was conducting experiments in his basement laboratory, disappeared and they believe he was killed by the Hawkline monster.  The novel reads like a product of the sixties -- surreal and drug-trippy in tone. 'Odd' describes it well.  Brautigan was a celebrated counter-culture writer and this was his only foray into science fiction.  His most famous novel is the even more odd *Trout Fishing in America* (1967).

[image: Cover of "The Hawkline Monster: A Gothic Western". A large, dark house is visible on the cover, with black smoke coming out of multiple chimneys, against a foggy background.]

Comment: This exactly.  Wow, you are good.  thanks.